# Orchard CMS. Exploring is admin panel opened or not

Tags: orchardcms

How can I explore in code what page is opened right now ,"admin panel" or "front-end" in Orchard CMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `AdminFilter.IsApplied(requestContext)`. It's true when user is in admin Dashboard.